# Xamarin Cross-Platform Project

Tags: xamarin

What is the difference between choosing a Cross-Platform Project (for example Shared) and add to a solution single Android and iPhone Project and a Shared Project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, except it saves some time. The templates in `Cross-Platform` are multi-project templates. It's just an easy way of creating a Xamarin solution with 2 clicks. Creating the projects one by one, gives you more control over the naming and such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for sharing code between cross-platform mobile applications: Shared Asset Projects and Portable Class Libraries. These options are [discussed here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/); more information on [Portable Class Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) and [Shared Projects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) is also available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was different: vs 2015 offers possibility to create a project template for cross platform but I Can create single project for specific platform. After that if I decide to add a PCL or a Shared Project is the same thing? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

PCL, it is the way, the truth, and the light. Friends don’t let friends use shared projects.

Okay so thats a bit strong but in general if you don’t know what you should do, go PCL. If you have a strong reason to use a shared project, sure, but otherwise go PCL, your lack of #ifdef and spaghetti code will thank me later. Among other things, PCL will ensure that code you write is going to be portable not just to all current platforms, but any future platforms we might support as well.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Extra information for you. 
[PCL vs Shared](https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/)